# How to debug NullReferenceException occuring on base.Dispose(disposing) boilerplate

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

I'm new to c# and VSTO.

I've got an Excel add in that I had working that creates a ribbon and a number of new buttons that do various things.

I'm getting an NullReferenceException on the base.Dispose in the Ribbon.Designer.cs file that occurs as the addin is loading into Excel.

From what the docs say I've probably instantiated something without using the new keyword but I've no idea where to find something that I didn't do!

I did have this working earlier today but haven't taken any backups or connected to source control which in hindsight was a bad idea!

At the time of the exception there are a lot of nulls and I don't know if this has significance?

Basically; I don't know what I did to suddenly make this occur and am not sure how to debug it, where to set my breaks or how this piece of boilerplate fits into the scheme of things.

I'm not expecting someone to magically pluck the bug out when I've not included vast majority of the code but some direction or interpretation of what to do would be fantastic!

**Locals window at time of exception**

```
  -           this  {ReportFramework.Ribbon}      ReportFramework.Ribbon
        -           base  {ReportFramework.Ribbon}      Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon.RibbonBase {ReportFramework.Ribbon}
        +           base  {ReportFramework.Ribbon}      System.ComponentModel.Component {ReportFramework.Ribbon}
                    Base  null  Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon.OfficeRibbon
        +           Context     '((Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon.RibbonBase)(this)).Context' threw an exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' object {System.NullReferenceException}
                    Factory     null  Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon.RibbonFactory
        +           Global      '((Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon.RibbonBase)(this)).Global' threw an exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException'  bool {System.NullReferenceException}
        +           Name  '((Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon.RibbonBase)(this)).Name' threw an exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException'    string {System.NullReferenceException}
        +           OfficeMenu  '((Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon.RibbonBase)(this)).OfficeMenu' threw an exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException'    Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon.RibbonOfficeMenu {System.NullReferenceException}
        +           Parent      '((Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon.RibbonBase)(this)).Parent' threw an exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException'  Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon.RibbonComponent {System.NullReferenceException}
        +           RibbonId    '((Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon.RibbonBase)(this)).RibbonId' threw an exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException'      string {System.NullReferenceException}
        +           RibbonType  '((Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon.RibbonBase)(this)).RibbonType' threw an exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException'    string {System.NullReferenceException}
        +           RibbonUI    '((Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon.RibbonBase)(this)).RibbonUI' threw an exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException'      Microsoft.Office.Core.IRibbonUI {System.NullReferenceException}
        +           StartFromScratch  '((Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon.RibbonBase)(this)).StartFromScratch' threw an exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException'    bool {System.NullReferenceException}
        +           Tabs  '((Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon.RibbonBase)(this)).Tabs' threw an exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException'    System.Collections.Generic.IList<Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon.RibbonTab> {System.NullReferenceException}
        +           Tag   '((Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon.RibbonBase)(this)).Tag' threw an exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException'     object {System.NullReferenceException}
        +           Non-Public members            
                    btnAddCETotals    null  Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon.RibbonButton
                    btnLinkBank null  Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon.RibbonButton
                    btnCEDataTransfer null  Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon.RibbonButton
                    *...More btn's*
                    IsClose     false bool
                    LargeColWidth     0.0   double
        +           objCReport  {ReportFramework.Classes.CReport}   ReportFramework.Classes.CReport
                    objFormat   null  ReportFramework.Classes.CFormat
                    oExcel      null  Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
                    PageWidthLandscape      0.0   double
                    PageWidthPortrait 0.0   double
                    SmallColWidth     0.0   double
                    tabBoyceTools     null  Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon.RibbonTab
                    userName    null  string
                    WorksheetResult   null  Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet
                    disposing   false bool
```

**Exception Detail**

```
  System.NullReferenceException was unhandled
    HResult=-2147467261
    Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
    Source=Microsoft.Office.Tools.Common.v4.0.Utilities
    StackTrace:
         at Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon.RibbonBase.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
         at ReportFramework.Ribbon.Dispose(Boolean disposing) in C:\Users\lsmith\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\xxx Tools 2\ReportFramework\Ribbon.Designer.cs:line 30
         at System.ComponentModel.Component.Finalize()
    InnerException:
```

Line 30 is the base.Dispose line below

**Ribbon.Designer.cs**

```
namespace ReportFramework
  {
      partial class Ribbon : Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon.RibbonBase
      {
          /// <summary>
          /// Required designer variable.
          /// </summary>
          private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

          public Ribbon()
              : base(Globals.Factory.GetRibbonFactory())
          {
              InitializeComponent();
          }

          /// <summary> 
          /// Clean up any resources being used.
          /// </summary>
          /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
          protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
          {
              if (disposing && (components != null))
              {
                  components.Dispose();
              }

              base.Dispose(disposing);

          }

          #region Component Designer generated code

          /// <summary>
          /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
          /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
          /// </summary>
          private void InitializeComponent()
          {
              this.tabBoyceTools = this.Factory.CreateRibbonTab();
              this.grpBoyceCAL = this.Factory.CreateRibbonGroup();
              this.btnGenerateCAL = this.Factory.CreateRibbonButton();
             *...Lots more code here; not sure if it's pertinent. can post if necessary.*

      }

      partial class ThisRibbonCollection
      {
          internal Ribbon Ribbon
          {
              get { return this.GetRibbon<Ribbon>(); }
          }
      }
  }
```

Comment: Is there any possibility Dispose is being called twice?

Comment: Google for "site:stackoverflow.com how to visual studio break on exception". NullReferenceException means that the the line where this problem happened looks like ```a.b()``` or ```c = a.b``` or .. and the   **a** (left side of the ```.```) is ```null``` and it should not be

Comment: RE Dispose being called twice jaket; It's possible but I can't find any calls / code containing that phrase, so will try xmojmr's suggestion of breaking on exception. Will let you know how I get on.

Comment: Hi xmojmr - can you please copy your comment into an answer? Found it straight away after enabling a 'Thrown' exception under Debug > Exceptions, expand Common Runtime > System and next to NullReference tick Thrown. Takes me to the exact line of code causing the issue which as the error described I look to be doing something without using 'New'

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, I started receiving this exception after checking the box in Project Settings > Signing for 'Sign the assembly' and trying to sign with the TemporaryKey.

I'm sure this error can be caused by a number of other mistakes but hopefully this helps someone.